# String Split and operation

Tags: java

```
public static void clacMethod() {
    int result = 0;
    // int i;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers to calculation");
    String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    String[] inputSplit = new String[input.length()];
    int[] output = new int[inputSplit.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSplit.length; i++) {
        if (input.contains("-")) {
            inputSplit = input.split("\\-");
            output[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[i]);
            result = output[0];
            result -= output[i];
        }
        if (input.contains("+")) {
            inputSplit = input.split("\\+");
            output[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[i]);
            result = output[0];
            result = result + output[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**how i have to work**

> How it have to work "+" and "-" operations on String input

// input should be like:  12+10-4
// output should be: 18

Comment: Check-out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java to know how to split strings in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if is not a school exercise use ScripEnginer

```
public double calc(String input) {
    int result;
    ScriptEngineManager sem= new ScriptEngineManager();    
    ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");     
    result = (Double)engine.eval(input)
    return result;
}
```

where input is a String "12+10-4"
and result will be a double 8